# Drop duplicate values based on one specific colum having into account level 0 in multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multiindex dataframe like the following:

```
df = {'Modality': {('0020413', '1', '6/21/2017', 'DTI'): 1,
  ('0020413', '1', '6/21/2017', 'FLAIR'): 1,
  ('0020413', '1', '6/21/2017', 'T1'): 1,
  ('0020413', '3', '8/27/2019', 'DTI'): 1,
  ('0020413', '3', '8/27/2019', 'FLAIR'): 1,
  ('0020413', '3', '8/27/2019', 'T1'): 1,
  ('0021261', '1', '3/15/2017', 'DTI'): 1,
  ('0021261', '1', '3/15/2017', 'FLAIR'): 1,
  ('0021261', '1', '3/15/2017', 'T1'): 1,
  ('0021261', '2', '4/24/2018', 'DTI'): 1,
  ('0021261', '2', '4/24/2018', 'FLAIR'): 1,
  ('0021261', '2', '4/24/2018', 'T1'): 1,
  ('0021261', '3', '5/01/2019', 'DTI'): 1,
  ('0021261', '3', '5/01/2019', 'FLAIR'): 1,
  ('0021261', '3', '5/01/2019', 'T1'): 1},
 'Phase': {('0020413', '1', '6/21/2017', 'DTI'): 1,
  ('0020413', '1', '6/21/2017', 'FLAIR'): 1,
  ('0020413', '1', '6/21/2017', 'T1'): 1,
  ('0020413', '3', '8/27/2019', 'DTI'): 1,
  ('0020413', '3', '8/27/2019', 'FLAIR'): 1,
  ('0020413', '3', '8/27/2019', 'T1'): 1,
  ('0021261', '1', '3/15/2017', 'DTI'): 1,
  ('0021261', '1', '3/15/2017', 'FLAIR'): 1,
  ('0021261', '1', '3/15/2017', 'T1'): 1,
  ('0021261', '2', '4/24/2018', 'DTI'): 1,
  ('0021261', '2', '4/24/2018', 'FLAIR'): 1,
  ('0021261', '2', '4/24/2018', 'T1'): 1,
  ('0021261', '3', '5/01/2019', 'DTI'): 1,
  ('0021261', '3', '5/01/2019', 'FLAIR'): 1,
  ('0021261', '3', '5/01/2019', 'T1'): 1}}
```

I have been trying to drop some duplicated values in the level_3 column, it doesn't appear in this sample of my data as it's very huge and I can't get the specific rows where the values are duplicated, but sometimes for each 'level_0' there are more than three values in 'level_3'. The values are repeated, for example you can find 'DTI, FLAIR, FLAIR, T1, T1' for one single 'level_0'

I've been trying:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset = 'Description', keep = "first")
```

but I got this error:

> KeyError: Index(['Description'], dtype='object')

I believe that's because the dataframe is multiindex, but I can't find information about drop duplicates in multiindex dataframes.

Can you help me?

Comment: can you share the source code : -> `df.to_dict()`

Comment: Thanks @AnuragDabas, but using what you proposed the whole dataset is being deleted except for one row, it doesn't work

Comment: yes, but they are for each level 0, and I want to keep every level 0 with 3 values in level 3

Comment: `df=df[df.index.get_level_values(3).isin(['DTI', 'FLAIR', 'T1'])]`?....btw this statement *"want to keep every level 0 with 3 values in level 3"* doesn't match with your question title *"Drop duplicates in multiindex dataframe"* **!!**

Comment: Ok, I'll change it. This last suggestion doesn't work either :( It's no deleting anything

Comment: so the goal here is to keep only these 3 values `['DTI', 'FLAIR', 'T1']` at level 3?

Comment: Yes, but to keep them in every level 0, I mean, the first row at level 0 ('0020413') has to have 3 values ['DTI', 'FLAIR', 'T1'] at level 3, not ['DTI', 'FLAIR', 'FLAIR', T1', T1] or any other repetition. Same for the second row at level 0 ('0021261') and so on

Comment: @al-yhuwertmurcia murcia Did you get your expected output?

Comment: It's strange that `df=df[df.index.get_level_values(3).isin(['DTI', 'FLAIR', 'T1'])]` doesn't work but anyway...happy coding **:)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC

try:

```
df=df.reset_index()

out=df[df['level_3'].isin(['DTI', 'FLAIR', 'T1'])]

out=out.drop_duplicates(['level_0','level_1','level_2','level_3']).set_index(['level_0','level_1','level_2','level_3'])

out.index.names=[None,None,None,None]
```

Now if you print `out` you will get your expected output